# Another proof of $|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|^2 = |\vec{a}|^2\cdot|\vec{b}|^2 - (\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2$.

Tags: geometry, vectors

I know how to prove the formula $|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|^2 = |\vec{a}|^2\cdot|\vec{b}|^2 - (\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2$, but my teacher asked me to prove it by using the formula $(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times\vec{c} = (\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c})\vec{b} - (\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})\vec{a}$, how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality $\vec{a}\ne\vec{0}$. Set $\vec{c}=\vec{a}$ so$$(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times\vec{a}=a^2\vec{b}-\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\right)\vec{a}.$$This is a cross product of perpendicular vectors, so its square modulus is$$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|^2a^2=a^4b^2+\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\right)^2a^2-2a^2\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\right)^2=a^2\left(a^2b^2-\left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\right)^2\right).$$Now cancel the $a^2$ factors.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly differently:

Let $\vec c= \vec a \times \vec b$, and use $(\vec P \times \vec Q). \vec R=\vec P. (\vec Q \times \vec R)$, and $\vec P \times (\vec Q \times \vec R)=(\vec P. \vec R)\vec Q-(\vec P. \vec  Q) \vec R$, then
$$|\vec a \times \vec b|^2=
(\vec a \times \vec b).(\vec a \times \vec b)= (\vec a \times \vec b).\vec c=\vec a.(\vec b \times \vec c)= \vec a.[\vec b \times (\vec a \times \vec b)]$$ $$=\vec a.[ b^2 \vec a- (\vec b. \vec a) \vec b]= a^2b^2-(\vec a.\vec b)^2.$$